# ASP.NET MVC core 5 _layout menu item changes links depending on the subpage

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm not sure why the created link isn't consistent.  In my _layout.cshtml shared view I have this:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" 
   asp-area="" 
   asp-controller="Repairs"
   uiactions="Index">Repairs</a>
```

This creates

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" uiactions="Index" href="/Repairs">Repairs</a>
```

when clicked on from a page other than a Repairs/Detail page that can be chosen from within the Index page.  However when I'm in the Repairs/Detail partial page, the _layout entry now creates this:

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" uiactions="Index" href="/Repairs/Detail">Repairs</a>
```

How do I write my _layout entry so that it always loads Index.cshtml?

Comment: What is  your uiactions? The default html5 seems not have such attributes.

Comment: @QingGuo - good question.  I have no idea where I got that from

Comment: It is an available attribute in ASP.NET core 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the follow code. Change  ***uiactions="Index"***  into    ***asp-action="Index"***

```
 <li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Repairs" asp-action="Index">Repairs</a>
 </li>
```